# How to trigger front flash at Samsung after upgrade Oreo

Tags: android, flash, camera

We got many samsung user complain that our app's camera "front LED flash" cannot work normal after they upgrade to Android Oreo. But it is work normal at native camera. (so it should not hardware broken issue)

After check, we found that after upgrade to Android Oreo, we cannot get any flash capability from "getSupportedFlashModes" (camera1). We also tried camera2, but it not work either.

```
    // Camera1
    Camera.Parameters cameraParameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<String> supportList = cameraParameters .getSupportedFlashModes();

    // Camera2
    mCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
```

Our app is work normal before upgrade Oreo, and it also work at non-Samsung device. Is there any think I miss? or is there any tricky way to control samsung front flash ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Front flash? There's no front flash on Samsung devices.

Comment: There are some model have front flash, ex Galaxy J7 ,J8 ,A6,... here is link for u reference https://www.91mobiles.com/list-of-phones/samsung-mobiles-with-front-flash

Comment: The Camera system on Android was changed back in Android 6.0 from first come, first serve to being based on priority (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-camera). The APIs that you need to use to support front flash might have changed because of this and you may need to look at the documentation for torch mode (not really sure though) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager#setTorchMode(java.lang.String,%20boolean)

Comment: "setTorchMode" is use for trigger flash without open camera, That is not my use case, We use front flash for camera take selfie, Anyway, I also try this function on Samusng device. It work fine at rear LED Torch, but still not work on front LED Torch....sad...